# LUA 5.1 and python classes

Tags: python, class, lua, lua-5.1

You know how when your making a class in python you do,

```
class className(object):
    def __init__(self):
        # INIT called first in a class
```

my question is how would you do this in lua? Is there even classes in lua? If so what in Lua is like the python function  `__init__()`
I'm just starting to learn Lua 5.1 and I noticed that i haven't run into classes.
Is Luas table system used for making classes in Lua, for example.

```
function getName(name) return name end
local className -- class
className['getName'] = getName
className.getName('name')
```

Comment: Though I kinda like Lua better then python because of the tables, I like being able to do `func = {} func['name'] = 'name'` then calling `func.name` instead of python dict `func['name']`

Comment: Actually, `className.__new__` would be called before `className.__init__`.  The former creates a new instance of the class and then the latter handles the initialization of that instance.

Comment: I forgot about `__new__` i've never felt the need to use it that might be why.